# How datas pass through in a android wifi direct connection

Tags: android, connection, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I would like to know how datas transit in a group of wifi direct devices. Assuming that we have a group of 3 wifi direct devices A, B and C. A is the owner of the group. Now, if B wants to send datas through wifi direct to C, will datas of B be sent directly to C or they are obliged to pass by A (the group owner) and then be redirect to C?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will pass through A but A will not be able to see them. This is useful as B and C need not be even in each others range.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so and correct me if I'm wrong, the domain of a group of many devices is equal to the range of the owner group?